# View Overlaps when back button pressed in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app i have one activity and multiple fragments,From Activity A onCreate() i just show my HomeFragment and after user click events on  my HomeFragment it moves to different fragment Like AboutFragment,Galleryfragment etc.

My problem is that when user move like ->HomeFragment -> AboutFragment ->GalleryFragment amd hen press virtual back button then view of GalleryFragment and AboutFragment  overlaps each other.

I am using following code when move between fragment-

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment mFragment = new AboutFragment();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, mFragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
```

So how can i solve this issue.

and i saw following eror in logcate-

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: AboutFragment{41c8a878 #0 id=0x7f07003d}
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1175)
 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:722)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1516)
```

EDIT:

my onCreateView of AboutFragment is-

```
          @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.aboutview, container,false);
             aboutView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.about_textview);
             return view;
          }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: u r using replace or add, make sure in u r code and tel.

Comment: @Tamilselvan Kalimuthu i am using replace

Comment: post u r oncreateview of the fragment

Comment: @ Tamilselvan Kalimuthu i have updated my question.

Comment: you should maintain the back stack of for each fragment.

Comment: @ Piyush Gupta how to maintain back stack can you please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608709/using-onsaveinstancestate-with-fragments-in-backstack , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252236/how-to-persist-fragment-data-after-backstack-transactions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999426/android-onconfigurationchanged-how-to-save-and-restore-fragment-back-stack see this